# When appending childnode, its throwing error "Property 'appendChild' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf<Element>'."

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodes, appendchild

when appending child node to *li* , getting error like *Property 'appendChild' does not exist on type 'NodeListOf'*

```
let li: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelectorAll("name li");  

        var newItem = document.createElement("li");
        var ListValue = document.createTextNode("abcd");
        var ListValue = document.createTextNode("efgh");
        var ListValue = document.createTextNode("ijkl");


        newItem.appendChild(ListValue);
        li.appendChild(ListItem);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` is an array and not an element, you should iterate over your `li` variable, but I'm guessing that you want to add an item to an existing list, if this is the case you should append the item to the list container `<ul>...</ul>`

EDIT: use `document.querySelector` to select only a specific element

Also, it's bad practice to define new custom html tags, try to use a class instead, so for an html like this:

```
<ul class="test">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

use this:

```
let li: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelector("ul.test");

var newNumberListItem = document.createElement("li");
var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("java");
var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("ajax");
var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("javascript");

newNumberListItem.appendChild(numberListValue);
li.appendChild(newNumberListItem);
```

Tip: if you are using ES6, avoid using `var` and use `const` for values that won't change on your scope and `let` for variables

```js
    let li: NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelector("ul.test");

    var newNumberListItem = document.createElement("li");
    var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("java");
    var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("ajax");
    var numberListValue = document.createTextNode("javascript");

    newNumberListItem.appendChild(numberListValue);
    li.appendChild(newNumberListItem);
```

```html
    <ul class="test">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`li` is a `NodeListOf<Element>`, it is not itself an `Element` so it does not have an `appendChild` method. Most likely what you wanted to do is address an element in your list:

```
li[0].appendChild(newNumberListItem);
```